Build Tauri from Flatpak Sandbox
I've installed VSCodium on my Fedora desktop as a Flatpak.
I have installed the node.js Flatpak SDK, together with pnpm as package manager.
When I create a Tauri app (version 2.0 - Release Candidate, currently) I get an error yelling at me that the WebKit GTK library is not found: since we're in the flatpak terminal there's no such thing as dnf or apt.
My question is: how do I get the Tauri app to build inside a Flatpak sandbox?

Although you could compile the WebKit GTK SDK from scratch (overall it's doable with more niche libraries - especially if you want to patch them), you're better off just running VSCodium with the org.gnome.Sdk like so:
flatpak run --runtime=org.gnome.Sdk//45 com.vscodium.codium

Please note that you need to explicitly set the SDK version: in this case number 45 included all the correct libraries, but it might change - keep an eye on the changelog.
And then from inside you may create the app with:
pnpm create tauri-app --rc

Or, if you had already created the app and want to develop it:
pnpm tauri dev

